# WPF Displatcher, How to stop threads made when i click on a new button

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to build a wpf application. I have made a grid that contains a datagrid. Inside the datagrid I have some data from a mysql database.

What I want to do is to refresh that data in "realTime", so I have created a textbox containing string "true" and checking if that textbox is "true" then do:

```
Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                }
                stopwatch.Stop();

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { reload_openPar(); }));
            });
```

`reload_openPar()` gets data from mysql database and checks the value from textbox. Again if it is "true" runs the same task.

Then I have a button that when pressed it is supposed to change the textbox value to "false" and then set some other data to datagrid.

Problem is that when I press that button it runs, I get the data that I am supposed to and then it goes back to data from `reload_openPar()`.

How can I workaround that problem?

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Show us how *you* tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us *exactly* what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I think you may have a problem when you have `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { reload_openPar(); }` inside the `reload_openPar()` method. I don't think that's going to end well....

Comment: Slugster thanks a lot. Bradley and BK i think that i have asked a question when i sayd what i want to do and i quote "Now i want when i press a btn to stop all the dispather.invokes and then fill a grid with other data from the database". I just puted the code there and i look for a workaround. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3193190 Stating your intentions does not constitute a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is used mainly to update UI components with data that is retrieved of secondary (non-UI)/background threads. Dispatcher marshals you back to the UI/Main thread of the application.

In your code, you don't want to do all the work in reload_openPar method within Dispatcher.BeginInvoke. Let the Task do the work and then just wrap the UI component access within a Dispatcher.Invoke call.

Comment: Thanks very VERY much for the answer. This solved everything to my code and my thinking.